# Can't bind to 'matDatePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy teniendo problemas para incluir el datepicker de angular material en mi aplicación.

En mi app.module.ts lo importo así:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RoutingAppointment, 
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule
  ],
  exports:[
    MatDatepickerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y posteriormente en mi componente en el html lo llamo de la siguiente forma (copy pasteado de la doc de angular material):

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatePicker]="picker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Sin embargo me está dando el error:

> Can't bind to 'matDatePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

¿Alguién sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado. En el html estaba mal escrito el nombre del atributo.

En vez de `[matDatepicker]` que es la forma correcta, tenía `[matDatePicker]` con la P mayúscula, lo cual es incorrecto.

Una tontería como un piano de cola.

Answer (score 0):

Suena a que no has importado el módulo correspondiente:

Tienes que elegir entre `MatMomentDateModule` (que dependerá de `moment.js`) y `MatNativeDateModule` (que usará la clase `Date` nativa de Javascript).

Por otro lado, asegúrate de tener también importados `FormsModule` y (dependiendo de qué tipo de formularios crees) `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Pues encontrar más información (en inglés) [aquí](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#troubleshooting)

Comment: Ya he probado a añadir MatNativeDateModule a mi app.module y añadirlo al array de imports pero no hay manera de que deje de dar el error.

Comment: ¿y FormsModule?

Comment: FormsModule está importado también